# Is it possible to alternate item labels above and below the data point in a xy scatter line graph?

Tags: java, jfreechart

I am currently making xy scatter plot, and i have code for setting the properties of my line graph.

```
private static void setLineProp(XYPlot plot, Color c) {
    XYLineAndShapeRenderer renderer = new XYLineAndShapeRenderer();
    renderer.setBaseItemLabelGenerator(new StandardXYItemLabelGenerator());
    renderer.setSeriesShapesVisible(0, true);
    renderer.setBaseItemLabelsVisible(true);
    renderer.setSeriesPositiveItemLabelPosition(0, new ItemLabelPosition(
            ItemLabelAnchor.OUTSIDE12, TextAnchor.BASELINE_CENTER));

    renderer.setSeriesPaint(0, c);
    plotRev.setRenderer(0, renderer);
}
```

This will generate a label for every data point on top of the line graph, but some points are very close together and causes the labels to become jumbled and unreadable.

I was wondering if there is a way to alternate individual point label above and below the line graph or even alternate the label offset so that the text does not jumble up?

Comment: Would tooltips work?

Comment: i tried using tool tips, but I could not get it to show up for every point. I ended up tilting the labels 45 degrees so it doesn't overlap with other labels.

Comment: I don't know a better alternative.